# Bezier Circle looks flattened like Tapeworm

Tags: bezier-curves

This problem is pretty simple. I am trying to make a perfectly round tube like a pipe. I made a bezier circle and increased the depth to make it thicker but now it looks like a flattened oval. How do I make this tube perfectly circular?

Here is what it looks like.
[image]
[image]

Also here is a link to the file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MTGfBifYD83TE8cU6sdVPGwCYmk-7dNy/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've scaled it on the Z axis, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> if you want to reset its scale:

[image]

You can also apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, but in that case, you may need to bring back the vertices radius to 1 in the *N* panel in *Edit* mode:

[image]